# computation of gradient vector field in 3D using GradientOrientationFilter

Tags: vector, image3d, image-processing

I want to compute a 3D gradient vector field of an `Image3D` object using the built-in [GradientOrientationFilter](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GradientOrientationFilter.html) function in *Mathematica*. From the documentation I extracted the example for computing the gradient vector field for the 2D case and put it into a module:

```
computeGradientField2D[image_Image] := Module[
   {dims, dirs, magnitudes},
   
   dims = ImageDimensions[image];
   dirs = ImageData[GradientOrientationFilter[image, 5]];
   magnitudes = ImageData[GradientFilter[image, 5]];
    MapThread[#1 {-Sin[#2], Cos[#2]} &, {magnitudes, dirs}, 2]
   ];
```

For drawing the vectors I also use the method from the documentation:

```
Show[ImageAdjust@img, 
 ListVectorPlot[
  MapIndexed[{{#2[[2]], dims[[2]] - #2[[1]]}, #1} &, or, {2}], 
  VectorColorFunction -> (Yellow &), VectorPoints -> Fine], 
 ImageSize -> 256]
```

This gives me the following output for a grayscale image of cell nuclei (left: raw image, right: raw image with overlaid vector field):

> [image] [image]

So far so good. Now I am struggling with the computation of the gradient vector field for `Image3D` objects. My current function looks like the following:

```
computeGradientField3D[image_Image3D] := Module[
   {img, dims, dirs, magnitudes},
   dims = ImageDimensions[image];
   dirs = ImageData[GradientOrientationFilter[image, 5]];
   magnitudes = ImageData[GradientFilter[image, 5]];
    MapThread[#1 {Cos[#2[[1]]], Sin[#2[[1]]] Cos[#2[[2]]], 
       Sin[#2[[1]]] Sin[#2[[2]]]} &, {magnitudes, dirs}, 3]
   ];
```

I am particularly not sure about the last line with the `MapThread` where the orientations of the vectors are created and multiplied with the magnitudes. The documentation of `GradientOrientationFilter` contains the following information about how to interpret the orientation angles:

> [image]

**Questions:**

**1. Am I misinterpreting the documentation?**

**2. How do I visualize the gradient vector field in the end (*e.g.* using `ListVectorPlot3D`)?**